# Cast lambda to std::function with parameter pack

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++17

There are several questions on SO that relate to casting lambdas to `std::function`s, but I have yet to see one that uses a parameter pack for the argument list. This seems broken on my version of g++ (7.1.1-4), and possibly it's just not supported. So is this legal c++17 (by the standard)? If not, why?

```
#include <functional>

template <typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs>
void Functor(std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> f) {}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto x = [] (int a, int b) { return a * b; };
    Functor<int, int, int>(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above won't compile because it fails type deduction. Obviously explicitly typing `x` as `std::function<int (int, int)>` instead of using `auto` makes the error go away. But that doesn't allow me to pass an r-value to `Functor` as I would like. I would also like to not loose any type-safety by using another template parameter for the function type.

What I really don't understand is why the above code fails to compile, but the below code is fine and works:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename TReturn, typename TArgA, typename TArgB>
void Functor(std::function<TReturn (TArgA, TArgB)> f) {}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto x = [] (int a, int b) { return  a * b; };
    Functor<int, int, int> (x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler doesn't know that you've intended `int, int` to be the whole of `TArgs`, and so tries to deduce the remainder of `TArgs` from the argument `f`.

For example, this would be valid:

```
Functor<int, int, int>(std::function<int(int, int, char, float)>{});
// TArgs := {int, int, [...]                       char, float}
```

So you need to instruct the compiler to not try to deduce the remainder of `TArgs`. For example, you could write:

```
(*Functor<int, int, int>)(x);
```

Or you could write `Functor` with a non-decomposed signature `Sig`:

```
template <Sig>
void Functor(std::function<Sig> f) {}
```

Or you could wrap the use of `TArgs` in the parameter `f` in a non-deduced context:

```
template <typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs>
void Functor(std::function<std::conditional_t<false, void, TReturn (TArgs...)>> f) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

This fails:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs>
void Functor(std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> f) {}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto x = [] (int a, int b) { return a * b; };
    Functor<int, int, int>(x);
    return 0;
}
```

because you're not specifying that the entirety of `TArgs...` is `{int, int}`. What you are doing is specifying that the first two types are `{int, int}`. Effectively, by providing those three types, we've turned the deduction problem into:

```
template <typename ... TArgs>
void Functor(std::function<int(int, int, TArgs...)> f) {}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto x = [] (int a, int b) { return a * b; };
    Functor(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile because a lambda isn't a `std::function` (or derived from one), which is the same reason you couldn't have called this without having provided any types to begin with.

The non-variadic version doesn't have this problem, since you've provided all the types.

---

But really, what you want is:

```
template <typename F>
void Functor(F ) {}
```

This doesn't lose you any type safety. It's using `std::function` that loses type information, since that class template exists to type erase.

Answer (score 2):

It is very rarely a good idea to cast a lambda to a `std::function` in a `template` if you are just going to call it.  `std::function` is type-erasure, and templated type erasure only makes sense if you are going to "pass it on" somewhere else and/or return it.

In any case, try this:

```
template <class Sig>
void Functor(std::function<Sig> f) {}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  auto x = [] (int a, int b) { return a * b; };
  Functor<int(int, int)>(x);
  return 0;
}
```

but you should really just do

```
template <class F>
void Functor(F f) {}
```

which is perfectly type-safe.

If you want early type checking, you could write

```
template<class Sig, class F>
struct signature_compatible;
template<class R, class...Args, class F>
struct signature_compatible<R(Args...), F> :
  std::is_consructible< R, std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>
{};
```

then do

```
template <class Sig, class F>
void Functor(F f) {
  static_assert( signature_compatible<Sig, F&>::value, "bad signature" );
}
```

but only if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will let you call `functor` without specifying it's template argument:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> struct Fun_trait {};

template <class T, class... Args, class Ret>
struct Fun_trait<auto (T::*) (Args...) const -> Ret>
{
    using F = std::function<auto (Args...) -> Ret>;
};


template <class TReturn, class... TArgs>
void functor(std::function<TReturn (TArgs...)> f) {}

template <class F>
std::void_t<decltype(&F::operator())>
functor(F f)
{
    return functor<typename Fun_trait<decltype(&F::operator())>::F>(f);
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    auto x = [] (int a, int b) { return a * b; };

    // nice and easy:
    functor(x); 

    return 0;
}
```

This is just a lazy first draft to get you started. You need to expand it to support forwarding and non-const `operator()`.

---

It works in 2 stages:

1st we have `Fun_trait` who - for pointer method types (e.g. the `operator()` of a lambda) - has defined an alias `F` for the required `std::function` argument type.

Next we have a overload of your function `functor` which via SFINAE with `std::void_t` kicks in only for functors with a non-overloaded `operator()` (e.g. a lambda) and then using the above trait calls the main function `functor` with the correct template argument deduced.